Amadeus "On-Demand Flight Status" API issue when there are two flights (legs)
I experience some problems when trying to receive status of the flight with several "legs" (several flights per day with the same flight number).
Example: carrierCode=DL, flightNumber=2694, scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-31 (for test you can pick any future date, it's daily regular flight).
When you load this flight information using "On-Demand Flight Status" API, you'll get two legs because there are two flights: LGA->MCO and MCO->LGA. However if you check the information returned in "flightPoints" you'll see that it is incomplete. In the response you can only find info about LGA (departure for LGA->MCO and arrival for MCO->LGA) and nothing about MCO.
Here is an example of response:
{
    "meta": {
        "count": 1,
        "links": {
            "self": "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/schedule/flights?carrierCode=DL&flightNumber=2694&scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-31"
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "DatedFlight",
            "scheduledDepartureDate": "2024-10-31",
            "flightDesignator": {
                "carrierCode": "DL",
                "flightNumber": 2694
            },
            "flightPoints": [
                {
                    "iataCode": "LGA",
                    "departure": {
                        "terminal": {
                            "code": "C"
                        },
                        "gate": {
                            "mainGate": "88A"
                        },
                        "timings": [
                            {
                                "qualifier": "STD",
                                "value": "2024-10-31T07:05-04:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "iataCode": "LGA",
                    "arrival": {
                        "terminal": {
                            "code": "C"
                        },
                        "gate": {
                            "mainGate": "86"
                        },
                        "timings": [
                            {
                                "qualifier": "STA",
                                "value": "2024-10-31T13:39-04:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "segments": [
                {
                    "boardPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "offPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "scheduledSegmentDuration": "PT6H34M"
                },
                {
                    "boardPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "offPointIataCode": "MCO",
                    "scheduledSegmentDuration": "PT2H50M"
                },
                {
                    "boardPointIataCode": "MCO",
                    "offPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "scheduledSegmentDuration": "PT2H39M",
                    "partnership": {
                        "operatingFlight": {
                            "carrierCode": "WS",
                            "flightNumber": 8063
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "legs": [
                {
                    "boardPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "offPointIataCode": "MCO",
                    "aircraftEquipment": {
                        "aircraftType": "321"
                    },
                    "scheduledLegDuration": "PT2H50M"
                },
                {
                    "boardPointIataCode": "MCO",
                    "offPointIataCode": "LGA",
                    "aircraftEquipment": {
                        "aircraftType": "321"
                    },
                    "scheduledLegDuration": "PT2H39M"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Is it a bug, or is there a way to get full information about such flights?
Request example: https://api.amadeus.com/v2/schedule/flights?carrierCode=DL&flightNumber=2694&scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-31

This is an issue with their API. The official response from Amadeus support states: This is occurring because the same flight number DL2694 is covering LGA-MCO-LGA. Consequently, the same IATA code is returned for both “departure” and “arrival.” In this instance, no information is returned for MCO..
However, this explanation does not address why incorrect information is being returned.
Ultimately, we opted to switch to a different provider, which effectively resolves the issue in the described scenario.
